# Is phosphorus a stereogenic centre in this phosphate ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, organophosphorus-compounds

[image]

My textbook says that in the above diagram that there is only 2 stereoisomers. I am guessing this is due to the stereogenic carbon atom and not due to the phosphorus atom which apparently isn't a stereoisomer.

[image]

However, it states that the above molecule has 4 stereoisomers. This must indicate that in this case the phosphorus atom, it is a stereogenic and gives rises to 2 stereoisomers.

Why is the phosphorus atom in A not a stereocenter while the phosphorus atom in B is a stereocenter?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In compound A, the negative and double bonded oxygens bound to the phosphorus are equivalent:

$\hspace{5.1cm}$[image: resonance]

In compound B, they are not equivalent:

$\hspace{7.5cm}$[image: no resonance]

Comment: An even better answer would point out that there isn’t really a $\ce{P=O}$ double bond in that molecule and that $\ce{\overset{-}{O}-\overset{+}{P}R2-\overset{-}{O}}$ would be the better depiction ;)